# Brightcove player onTemplateReady not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, brightcove

Can anyone explain why templateLoadHandler function's gets fired but not templateReadyHandler?

```
<param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded"/>
<param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady"/>
```

Those functions are getting executed in my AngularJS code, but even then, it doesn't make sense to me why myTemplateLoaded() gets fired and not onTemplateReady().

Any explanation would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this as well, I found that if you add a listener instead of trying to use a param, that works, see here:

```
const onTemplateLoaded = (id) => {
  const player = brightcove.api.getExperience(id);
  const videoPlayer = globalPlayer.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
  if(this.props.autoplay) {
    const videoExperience = globalPlayer.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
    videoExperience.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.ExperienceEvent.TEMPLATE_READY, () => videoPlayer.play());
  }
};
```